# A data structure for a phone book such that it can search a number by name and also search a name by number

Tags: data-structures, hash, dictionary, hashmap

Do you know a solution to the following interview question?

> Design a data structure for a phone book that can safely and
>   efficiently search a number by name and also search a name by number.

---

Details:

The solutions found on stackoverflow are all about hashtables, but, I'd have to build 2 hashtables for that, which requires twice the space.

How to do it with only one data structure in a time- and space-efficient, type-safe manner?

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for?  Specifically, why is my answer "not a solution"?

Answer (score 16):

Such data structures are known as **multi-index containers**. They are not very common in most programming languages, because the interface can get quite complex. 
There are implementations in [Java](http://code.google.com/p/multiindexcontainer/), [C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18864/Multi-Index-Container-for-C-2-0) and - most prominently - C++ with the Boost library, see [Boost.MultiIndex Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), in particular [example 4](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example4) about **bidirectional maps**:

> A bidirectional map is a container of (const FromType,const ToType) pairs such that no
>   two elements exists with the same first or second component (std::map
>   only guarantees uniqueness of the first component). Fast lookup is
>   provided for both keys. The program features a tiny Spanish-English
>   dictionary with online query of words in both languages.

The **basic idea of multi-index containers** is that a lot of containers store their elements in nodes that contain pointers/references to other nodes (e.g. double linked lists). Instead of only storing the pointers/references for a single container, a node contains the links for several index structures. This works at least with linked lists, sorted trees and unique hash indices. And the implementation is very efficient, because only one memory allocation is required per element.

Comment: Quite interesting, those multi-index containers (+1). So there's a one to one mapping between containers and nodes? Do all references within nodes point to other nodes?

Comment: +1 for thinking with more depth than multiple (uncontained/independent) hash maps. Well presented also. This sounds like a "more correct" method than others have presented as it maintains object oriented principals. The OP could write a class called "PhoneBook" which is an multi-index container for Names and Phone Numbers.

Comment: Still the best answer by far: +50. You could've answered my question, though. Rereading your explanation, I guess "container" is synonym to index structure, so a node contains exactly one value and at least one reference per container, right? Can multi-index containers be nested, or are they always flattened?

Answer (score 4):

Well.. I agree with the multi-index and it is the right way to do it. However, for a job interview, they probably want you to think about it and explain something, not just say use boost. If they ask about the internals of boost, it might be embarrassing if you can't explain it properly.

So, here is a possible solution.

First of all, do not use a hashtable for this. Phones and names can be easily sorted and you should probably use some balanced search tree, or a trie if you want interactive search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). IMHO, a hashtable is a big waste of space in this case.

Let us assume that names are unique and numbers are unique. Then, you can do:

1- Data structure to hold your data

```
struct Phone {
 // implement the phone here whatever they need
 // assume that whatever representation used can be converted into a unique id (number)
}; //
struct PhoneBookEntry {
   std::string name;
   Phone number;
};
```

2- Create two trees one for the name and one for the phone

```
BalancedSearchTree<PhoneBookEntry> tree_by_name;
BalancedSearchTree<PhoneBookEntry> tree_by_number;
```

3- That is it. Look up each tree for whatever you need

```
bool PhoneBook::getByName(const std::string &name, PhoneBookEntry &o) {
  tree_by_name.get(name, o);
  return !o.empty();
}
bool PhoneBook::getByNumber(const Phone &p, PhoneBookEntry &o) {
 tree_by_number.get(p, o);
 return !o.empty();
}
```

Good luck

Comment: +1 for mentioning space requirements of hashtables, and tries. But shouldn't lookups for a phone book be O(1)?

Answer (score 3):

Hash everything (i.e. both directions) into the same table.

Comment: @user1002288: In the case of number->name, then the key is the number.  In the case of name->number, then the key is the name.

Comment: Oli, so actually, you need to build 2 hashtable and put them into one, first part is name->number, second part .is number->name, right ?

Comment: @user1002288: No, you only need one (assuming that no-one has the name `555-6253`).  However, there is no real advantage to having only one, so I'm not really sure what the purpose of the question is...

Comment: suppose given: Jack --> 123 , Tom --> 456, if we use name as key, how to search a number given name ? e.g. given 456 how to find Tom ? thanks !

Comment: @user1002288: For every name-number pair, put both {key=name,value=number} and {key=number,value=name} into the table.

Comment: Simple solution :) But not type-safe :(

Comment: @OliCharlesworth this was a very lazy answer which is why it required a half a dozen comments to clarify. The OP is clearly a new user seeking expertise, not brief implied advice. Having the level of proficiency to fully understand your original answer would immediately imply having the level of proficiency needed to have solved the problem without asking for help in the first place. ;-)

Comment: A bidirectional map typically does exactly this (uses two mappings).  there is nothing wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this easy?

Using an array of record/struct/tuple of the value pair (telephone-number, name).

1. Do a linear search looking for the search key; O(n/2) for match,
   O(n) for miss,
2. return record/struct/tuple and do whatever needs to be done.

Edit:

This algorithm can be improved in many ways.

I think this interview question might be deliberately under specified in order to find out how the interviewee reacts. (That is what I do when I interview). So it may be more important to treat it as such, rather than assume it is just a Computer Science question.

I think it is worth engaging with the interviewer. For example:

1. Is it important that this is fast enough for a personal telephone directory, e.g. on a mobile phone (unlikely any reasonable algorithm will be too slow), or a country-size telecom infrastructure application where there may be availability, concurrent update, and extra requirements, for example access control to some subset of names and numbers?
2. What is the target technology? You might want to choose different approaches e.g. for Python, C++, assembler, ...
3. Are their more qualities it needs to demonstrate than time & space efficiency? For example, must it be easy to prove correct, or test? Is the CPU-saving by a fast approach worth the human expense of testing time?
4. How skilled or knowledgeable are the people maintaining and reusing code likely to be? Would simple approaches be favoured on maintenance cost grounds.

etc.

I think it is more important to engage with the interviewer, rather than only focusing on the technical solution. When I interview, I am looking for someone who tries to actually understand the whole problem rather than the (usually small) part which is easy to define.

Comment: That will work, but you can get more efficient than O(n) lookup time.

Comment: @blahdiblah - Sorry, I wasn't clear. I will expand my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 36-ary tree (26 for alphabets and 10 for digits) and have links pointing from both an alphabet as well as a digit to the same node. (This won't be a "tree" strictly speaking, but you get the idea). This way you won't get a constant time lookup but you won't have to repeat data and the lookup would still be pretty quick.

Of course, you'd have to handle collisions, but you'd have to handle them while using hashtables too.
Maybe you can use two pointers to point to the next collided node by name and by number.